# Broadcast peer-to-peer network

Tags: networking, p2p, broadcast

Can someone suggest some ways to implement a high-level design for 'broadcast peer-to-peer network'?

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're simply describing the internet.  No limit on nodes, nodes can join/leave anytime, redundant routing makes the network robust, load balancing can ensure you're not using some nodes too much.

Your last requirement... consistency... that really has nothing to do with the network.  What you're looking for is an eventually consistent data store, and without knowing more about your specific requirements, it's not possible to give you much more of a specific answer.  There are many tradeoffs you need to choose related to the data size, latency, atomicity, sharding, replication factor, etc.